# XSD Two elements with the same name but different attribute value

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to define an XSD template for the following:

```
<template_data>
  <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
  <given_name lang="CES">Žlutý</given_name>
</template_data>
```

So far, I've come up with

```
<xs:complexType name="attribute_CES">
  <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="CES"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="attribute_ENG">
  <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="ENG"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="template_data">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="given_name" type="attribute_CES"/>
      <xs:element name="given_name" type="attribute_ENG"/>          
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Problem is, this defines an element with one and the same name two times, each time with a different type, to which any XSD validator I've found protests.

As far as I know, you can require an attribute to have a specific value with the `fixed` option, and that is included in the definition of a (complex) type. So if you want the attribute with a different value, you would have to define a new type.

What I need is the `template_data` to include both `given_name`s, exactly once with `lang="CES"`, and exactly once with `lang="ENG"`. Is there a way to write an xsd validation schema for that, or is that impossible (for example if the xml input doesn't conform to standards)?

Comment: This is not possible with XSD since this means validating the content - XSD can only validate the schema. You'll need something like [Schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) to achieve what you need.

Comment: Really? I've seen some basic content validation with XSD, using `restriction` (http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp) and with `fixed` in attributes (http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp), or with types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't declare two elements with the same name with different types in the same context, but I think I understand what you want to do.

If you really had elements with very different contents, it would make sense to create two types (and it would also make sense for them to have different names or to at least occur in another context). Since your data is similar, and the main difference is an attribute which describes the text content of the element, you can create one type and restrict the values the attribute can receive:

```
<xs:complexType name="languageType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="lang" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="ENG"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="CES"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

In `languageType` above you have simple content (`xs:string`) and a required `lang` attribute which can only have two values: `ENG` or `CES`.

If you want to guarantee that there are exactly two elements, you can restrict that in your `template_data` element definition with `minOccurs="2"` and `maxOccurs="2"` for the `given_name` child element:

```
<xs:element name="template_data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="given_name" type="languageType" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2"/>        
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    ...
```

Now it is still possible to have two `given_name` elements with the same `lang="ENG"` attribute. To restrict that we can add a `xs:key` definition in the context of `template_data` element definition:

```
<xs:element name="template_data">
    <xs:complexType> ... </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="languageKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="given_name" />
        <xs:field xpath="@lang"/>
    </xs:key>
</xs:element>
```

The `xs:key` uses the nested `given_name` as a selector and its `lang` attribute as the key field. It won't allow duplicate fields, that means it will not allow two `given_name` elements with the same `lang` atrributes. Since you only allow two, and they can only be `ENG` or `CES`, one has to be `ENG`, and the other `CES`.

Now these XML document validate:

```
<template_data>
    <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
    <given_name lang="CES">Žlutý</given_name>
</template_data>

<template_data>
    <given_name lang="CES">Žlutý</given_name>
    <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
</template_data>
```

But these don't:

```
<template_data>
    <given_name lang="FRA">Zluty</given_name>
    <given_name lang="CES">Žlutý</given_name>
    <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
</template_data>

<template_data>
    <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
    <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
</template_data>

<template_data>
    <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
</template_data>

<template_data>
    <given_name>Zluty</given_name>
    <given_name lang="ENG">Zluty</given_name>
</template_data>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I was looking for! Out of curiosity, would this still work with another element, e.g. last_name, with similar rules as given_name? I mean two given_names with lang CES and ENG, and two last_names with lang CES and ENG.

Comment: Yes, but you would have to define a second key for the last name, since the keys are unique within a given scope. You also would have to move the occurrence constraints to the `sequence` element if you want to keep first-name and last-name together. You could also wrap them in a parent `name` element, and use only one key for the parent element.